# ajax call FROM fb app canvas page -- TO secure URL hosted on hostgator -- CodeIgniter

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, hosting

my facebook app developed in CodeIgniter, hosted on hostgator, was working fine before i switched to secure URL. Here is some information about app.

```
Site URL: http://sitename.com/
canvas URL: http://sitename.com/fbapp/
canvas Secure URL: https://secure10977.hostgator.com/~cpanelUser/sitename.com/fbapp/
```

CodeIgniter Config file:
    $config['base_url'] = 'https://secure10977.hostgator.com/~cpanelUser/sitename.com/fbapp/';

Now when i use application it loads fine but when i try to fetch somedata using ajax on app page i get a URL not found error. Ajax will post data to following URL.

```
https://secure10977.hostgator.com/~cpanelUser/sitename.com/fbapp/canvas/match
```

where canvas is controller and match is method.

Can someone tell me why do i get a 404-page not found error on ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your ajax url, it looks like you are using pretty urls?  Take a look in your .htaccess file for any offending rewrites.

The main application will work fine as it will just call the default document (index.php).

An easy way to test this would be to try to access

```
https://secure10977.hostgator.com/~cpanelUser/sitename.com/fbapp/index.php/canvas/match
```

Good luck :)

UPDATE:

Long shot, but trying to imagine what your .htaccess rewrite rule looks like, if it is something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Try changing it to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /~cpanelUser/sitename.com/fbapp/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: +1 for index.php..i am not getting error now.. but why do i need to add index.php when i have removed index.php using .htaccess?

Comment: can't say for sure - nothing sticking out in your .htaccess?  I'm not a hostgator customer, but i'm guessing you don't have access to you apache conf to make sure AllowOverride is set properly on SSL so that your .htaccess file is used?

Comment: if you can post your .htaccess file which does the rewrites for pretty urls it might help us all out :)

Comment: after adding index.php when i access url directly from browser i get json results..but in fb app same url endsup in error :( (it color changes to red and returns nothing )